# prove that $ f([0,1]) \in [0,1]$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

> Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that: $$ f(x) = e^{-{\frac{x^2}{3}}}$$
>   Prove that  $ \forall x \in [0,1] : f(x) \in [0,1]$.

I observe that function is continuous and bounded in that segment, it is a bijective function so it takes all values between $f(0)=1$ and $f(1)= e^ {-\frac {1}{3}}$. However, I do not now how to proceed. How can I prove the above statement?

Comment: Assume that $$e^{\frac{-x^2}{3}>1$$, and show a contradiction.

Comment: Why does bijectivity (as a function $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$) imply all the values are between f(0) and f(1)? What does the derivative of the function tell you?

Comment: I think because f(1) is its min and f(0) its max so it takes all values between f(0) and f(1), but I'm not sure :(

Comment: But how do you know $f(1)$ is a max and $f(0)$ is a min?

Comment: Because the function is decreasing  so f(0) is its max in [01]

Comment: How do you know $f$ is decreasing? If you can explain that, you're good.

Comment: because its first derivative

Comment: Exactly. You need to mention that in your proof.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve your problem is to find the extremum value of $f(x))$ as bellow:
$$ \left( f(x) \right)^\prime = -\frac{2x}{3} \cdot e^{-\frac{x^2}{3}}$$

By setting $(f(x))^\prime = 0$, we will obtain that $x = 0$, what is left to be done is show that the point $(0,1)$ is an maximum point, hence lets take a 
$$ f^"(x) = \frac{-2}{3} \cdot e^{-\frac{x^2}{3}} + \frac{4x^2}{9} \cdot e^{-\frac{x^2}{3}} = e^{-\frac{x^2}{3}} \cdot \left( \frac{4x^2}{9} - \frac{2}{3} \right)$$

Thus, by applying $x = 0$, yields
$$ f^"(0) < 0$$

which means that $(0,1)$ is a maximum point, thus
$$ f([0,1]) \in [0,1]$$